# SSIS Import UTF-8 TSV file into SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, encoding, utf-8, ssis

First time user/question:

I have numerous TSV files exported from a computer forensics application encoded as "Unicode (UTF-8)".  I created a package using visual studio 2013 and have a flat file connection manager where my code page is 65001 (UTF-8) and advanced settings are all unicode string (dt_wstr).  My OLE DB destination is hooked to a table with the same unicode settings, and the component properties have "always use default code page" = 65001 and set to true.

However, the package fails with the error:  "The data type for "Flat File Source.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[MyCOLUMN]" is DT_NTEXT, which is not supported with ANSI files. Use DT_TEXT instead and convert the data to DT_NTEXT using the data conversion component."

I'm puzzled:  How does this have anything to do with ANSI?  The file was exported encoded as UTF-8.  Now, as the error suggests, I can work around this by setting my connection manager advanced properties to Varchar (dt_str), then using a data conversion task to convert each and every field to dt_wstr, but that seems unnecessary.

Thank you.

Comment: try   SHOW ADVANCED EDITOR -> Input and Output Properties -> Flat File Source Output -> Output columns – Make sure that all of the character type columns are using DT_STR.

Comment: I should have stated that the data needs to be encoded UTF-8 (potentially many foreign characters).  So, the receiving table needs to be nvarchar.  So, if the source file is UTF-8 why is SSIS reading the file as ANSI and forcing me to do a data conversion?

Comment: Data type is defined(guessed by ssis) by reading  few record and it find data is ANSI no UTF8 ...